# ¿Por qué tan poco estudio sobre las vocales del español puertorriqueño?

Tags: pronunciación, dialectos, fonología, lingüística, vocales

Muchos de los fenómenos consonánticos del español puertorriqueño se saben (como la lenición de /s/ y /n/ finales, lateralización o lenición de la rótica implosiva, uvularización de /r/ y otros), pero no mucho se sabe de los fenómenos vocálicos del dialecto. Sé sobre la cerradura de vocales (una característica del subdialecto de Lares pero antes más extendido según Navarro Tomás, quien registró casos tan al este como Vieques), ensordecimiento y apócope de vocal final (fenómeno del noreste y este), y extensión del redondeamiento en diptongos crecientes con /w/ (y reducción de /we̞/ a lo que Navarro Tomás denomina como una "simple *e* labializada", en otras palabras, [ø̞]). Todos esos estudios son relativamente viejos. Nada reciente se sabe sobre los fenómenos vocálicos del dialecto y los subdialectos actuales (aparte de la cerradura de vocales finales) y qué influencia el inglés podría tener en la calidad fonética vocálica del dialecto (y en especial sobre el subdialecto de San Juan). La mayoría (si no casi todos) de los estudios recientes están concentrados sobre las consonantes. Entonces, ¿Por qué tan poco estudios sobre las vocales y diptongos del español puertorriqueño? Preguntado por hablante nativo del dialecto.

Comment: Fantástica pregunta cuyo foco podría cambiarse un poco: la medición del interés es algo difícil de calibrar y, en cualquier caso, fuera del ámbito de este sitio. En lo que podría ponerse el acento es en el análisis de los elementos que planteas. Es decir, más que plantear por qué no se estudia, ¿qué tal plantear casos para estudiarlo desee aquí? Animo a darle a [edit] para modificar en ese sentido

Comment: La pregunta suena interesante pero teniendo en cuenta que el español lo hablan 480 millones de personas y P.Rico tiene 2.8 millones (0.6%) de hablantes, se me hace apenas lógico que no haya muchos estudios tan particulares.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because Spanish vowels don't really change all that much. There are five standard vowels used throughout the Spanish-speaking world, less than in all other major Romance languages. Thus, most researchers aren't really interested in examining the vowels of a particular dialect.

However, in English, because there are many vowels and many differences between vowels (some of which can actually change the meaning of certain words), many studies can be done.